# Difference between caching methods in python

Tags: python, caching, joblib

What difference is there between using the `@cache` decorator from the built-in `functools` module and the one from `joblib`?

Also, [`@functools.cache`'s documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.cache) mentions

> Returns the same as lru_cache(maxsize=None), creating a thin wrapper around a dictionary lookup for the function arguments. Because it never needs to evict old values, this is smaller and faster than lru_cache() with a size limit.

which seems counter-intuitive to me: why would storing more values lead to a *smaller and faster* solution than `lru_cache()`?

Comment: The *smaller* and *faster* adjectives probably refer to the implementation of lru_cache

Comment: It uses less memory because it doesn't have to store last use time. Faster because it doesn't execute the code that would check the last use time.

Comment: From the documentation it looks like joblib caches results of entire job runs to disk. functools is an in-memory cache, intended for individual functions. See https://joblib.readthedocs.io/en/latest/memory.html#comparison-with-memoize